# Powershell elasticsearch not working, scrollId missing

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

I'm creating a PowerShell script to grab a large number of files from a public service (which I do not have any ownership over). I need to use the scroll API to get all the files I need but I’m running into a problem: Elasticsearch responds differently using postman and PowerShell when providing a scroll_id.

I've recreate these steps manually in postman without any issues.

```
Function scrollBody ($scrollID) {
    $scrollBody = @"
    {
        "scroll": "2m",
        "scroll_id": "$scrollId"
    }
"@
    return $scrollBody
}


    $body = (scrollBody `
        -scrollID $scrollID
    | ConvertFrom-Json)

    $scrollUri = $ServerUri + "/_search/scroll"
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest `
        -Method GET `
        -Uri $scrollUri `
        -ContentType 'application/json' `
        -Body $body `
        | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I have the working scroll id from another part of the code, but I’ve tested the ids, using postman and they are working fine.

I suspect it's the way I’m providing the body, but I’m stuck with this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: scrollId is missing;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: scrollId is missing;"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to provide what service it is that you're trying to query?

Comment: @AndrewRyanDavis yes it's a public service and requires no authentication either.
http://distribution.virk.dk/offentliggoerelser/_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test, but it appears you have a syntax error when calling your function to generate the object with the scrollID.

You can just add this into a hash of the request and it will be a bit easier to read. The backticks are somewhat of an antipattern.

```
$serverUri = 'http://distribution.virk.dk/offentliggoerelser/_search/scroll'

$iwrParams = @{
    'Uri'         = $serverUri
    'Method'      = 'GET'
    'ContentType' = 'applications/json'
    'UseBasicParsing' = $true
    'Body' = @{
        'scroll'    = '2m'
        'scroll_id' = $scrollId
    }
}

Invoke-WebRequest @iwrParams
```

Comment: Shouldn't the parameters contain the scroll id?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mistakenly removed it while I was testing because I do not know the `$scrollId` value. Looks like this is getting responses, though, now that I'm testing against the url you provided.